# Is there a way to generate a compiler warning when a specific property is accessed?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

The example is that I would like to generate a warning each time the property `-[UIViewController navigationController]` is accessed.

For the curious, the reason is that I am using a custom Navigation Controller, and would like to be warned when I (or other developers on the project) attempt to access this property.

Comment: Do you mean "accessed at compile time" or "accessed at runtime"?

Comment: How can accessing anything at runtime cause a compiler warning? Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: I take it to mean that if the specified line appears in code that it should generate a warning at compile time.  If the method is never called, then it should not.

Comment: Yes, I meant at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom getter and declare it as deprecated:

```
- (UINavigationController*)navigationController __attribute__ ((deprecated))
{
    // do something
}
```

This way only when someone tries to call this getter he'll get a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that comes to mind is to subclass UIViewController and only use your custom subclass as a base for other view controllers in the project.  That way, you can override the method and use #warning to get the preprocessor to emit a diagnostic. **(As noted below, #warning won't actually work.  Instead, you would need to write code in the overridden method to produce whatever diagnostic you considered appropriate.)**  Perhaps your custom navigation controller could check that its content controller belonged to the correct base class.

Bypassing that is a trivial cast but, if the point is to prevent accidental use, it might have some value.

Comment: Won't using #warning cause the compiler to generate a warning just by compiling the class?  He wants the warning whenever the class property is *accessed*.

Comment: Ouch!  You're right...I should have asked what his definition of "warning" was.